# How to find value from Gaussian distribution for given point, covariance matrix and expected value.

Tags: normal-distribution, covariance

While reading one article I came across that one of the values (probability) I am supposed to calculate is equal to N(v, b + (h^T)(W^T), I). Where b,v,h are vectors, W is a matrix and I is the appropriate identity matrix. 
All I could find out is that this stands for Normal distribution but couldn't really get too much further.